# Prevent browser URL from changing during page redirect in an SSL configuration using IBM HTTP server

Tags: apache, ssl, websphere

I have installed ibmhttp server as a plugin in websphere application server. I also configured httpd.conf file to allow for ssl connections and this serves the application as expected, however, two issues arise:

1. I noticed that after entering the URL to launch my app @ https://localhost/application-name, it redirects to the URL specified in the application's configuration. What I want is to have the https://localhost/application-name url, while the content of the application is served without changing the url to the application's configuration URL
2. I want to be able to type in the browser's URL address bar only the application-name and the URL should change to the localhost

For the httpd.conf file, after enabling the SSL module by uncommenting the  `LoadModule ibm_ssl_module modules/mod_ibm_ssl.so` and `Listen 0.0.0.0:443`,

I have the following virtual host declaration

```
    <VirtualHost *:443>
    SSLEnable
    SSLProtocolDisable SSLv2
   </VirtualHost>

   <VirtualHost localhost:443>
   SSLEnable
   SSLProtocolDisable SSLv2
   </VirtualHost>

  KeyFile "C:/Program Files (x86)/IBM/HTTPServer/ihskey(dot)kdb"
   SSLDisable
```

Comment: Please read [Under what circumstances may I add “urgent” or other similar phrases to my question, in order to obtain faster answers?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/326569) - the summary is that this is not an ideal way to address volunteers, and is probably counterproductive to obtaining answers. Please refrain from adding this to your questions.

Comment: @halfer, I apologize for the use of the word. I will definitely not add it to my questions in the future. This apologies also goes to anyone who may be offended by same. Thanks

Comment: @halfer, I have done an edit and removed it.

Comment: Thanks. It's not that people will be offended - irritated maybe. You'll probably find that a proportion of folks will avoid questions with this sort of demand, and some people may just downvote and move on. It's a matter of fairness - no question here can request higher priority treatment than other questions. Hope that helps!

Comment: Stack Overflow is a site for programming and development questions. This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming or development. See [What topics can I ask about here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) in the Help Center. Perhaps [Web Applications Stack Exchange](http://webapps.stackexchange.com/), [Webmaster Stack Exchange](http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/) or [Unix & Linux Stack Exchange](http://unix.stackexchange.com/) would be a better place to ask.

Answer (score 0):

If there's really just one URL in the application, you could configure IHS to pretend /application-name is that URL by using RewriteRule ^/application-name /the/real/URL [PT].

If your application, like most, uses multiple URL's, there's no server-side way to pretend it doesn't. If this is some weird vanity request, shove the entire thing in an iframe. If you have actual users, they'll probably tell you the user expereince is terrible and you'll have to undo it in the next way.

Net: if you want your app to behave like a single-page application, you need to design and implement it that way